# Baseline Profiles fail at profile generation with Shell.isSessionRooted

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, baseline-profile, macrobenchmark

I am trying to integrate the newly introduced [baseline profiles](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles/overview) into our app. I am using the following simple snippet to generate a baseline profile.

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class BaseProfileGenerator {

    @get:Rule
    val baselineProfile = BaselineProfileRule()

    @Test
    fun appStartup() {
        baselineProfile.collectBaselineProfile(packageName = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.packageName) {
        pressHome()
        startActivityAndWait()
     }
   }
}
```

However, on running the test on a gradle managed device/emulator, I am getting the following exception:

```java
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at androidx.benchmark.Shell.isSessionRooted(Shell.kt:165)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.BaselineProfilesKt$collectBaselineProfile$killProcessBlock$1.invoke(BaselineProfiles.kt:64)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.BaselineProfilesKt$collectBaselineProfile$killProcessBlock$1.invoke(BaselineProfiles.kt:60)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.BaselineProfilesKt.collectBaselineProfile(BaselineProfiles.kt:69)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.BaselineProfileRule.collectBaselineProfile(BaselineProfileRule.kt:94)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.BaselineProfileRule.collectBaselineProfile$default(BaselineProfileRule.kt:88)
    at com.package.name.baselineprofile.BaseProfileGenerator.appStartup(BaseProfileGenerator.kt:28)
    ... 36 trimmed
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2007)
    at androidx.benchmark.ShellImpl.createShellScript(Shell.kt:507)
    at androidx.benchmark.ShellImpl.<clinit>(Shell.kt:471)
    ... 44 more
```

According the the docs, it was stated that we need a userdebug/rooted device in order to generate the profile and I was under the impression gradle managed devices with aosp system image will satisfy that need.

For reference, here's the device in my build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
managedDevices {
    devices {
        add(
            ManagedVirtualDevice("pixel2Api31").apply {
                device = "Pixel 2"
                apiLevel = 31
                systemImageSource = "aosp"
            }
        )
    }
}
```

`Android Gradle Plugin = v7.3.1 macroBenchmarVersion = v1.2.0-alpha07 profileInstallerVersion = 1.3.0-alpha01`

Any idea what might be happening here? I searched around but couldn't find anything relevant.

I tried updating the dependencies to the latest alpha versions since apparently according to the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/benchmark#1.2.0-alpha06), baseline profiles no longer need rooted devices but even then its failing with the same exception.